# AdColony Integration Error (Error, platform-specific implementation not set)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, adcolony

I am facing an error in unity while implementing adcolony's sdk. I have attached a screenshot showing the errors.
I can not seem to figure out whats wrong since, the platform settings in unity are iOS, I am developing on a mac, and there are no errors while the unity player is not active. I really need help.[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGZ0G.png)

```
void Start(){
    if (!CUtils.IsBuyItem() && !CUtils.IsAdsRemoved())
    {
        RequestBanner();
        RequestInterstitial();
    }

    ConfigureVideoAds();
    RegisterForAdsCallbacks();
}

private void ConfigureVideoAds()
{
    appOptions.UserId = "";
    appOptions.AdOrientation = AdColony.AdOrientationType.AdColonyOrientationAll;

    string[] zoneIds = new string[] { iOSRewardedVideoID, iOSRewardedVideoID };

    AdColony.Ads.Configure(iOSAppKey, appOptions, zoneIds);
}


void RegisterForAdsCallbacks(){
    AdColony.Ads.OnRequestInterstitial += (AdColony.InterstitialAd ad) =>
    {
        _videoAd = ad;
    };

    AdColony.Ads.OnExpiring += (AdColony.InterstitialAd ad) =>
    {
        AdColony.Ads.RequestInterstitialAd(ad.ZoneId, null);
    };

    AdColony.Ads.OnRewardGranted += (string zoneId, bool success, string name, int amount) =>
    {
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please start by adding the code that throws the error, your AdManager.Start()

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post with the code